# Converting Perl number to MS SQL Server datetime

Tags: sql-server, perl, date, datetime, ssis

I have a datetime value generated by a Perl program, but it's format is a number.
It looks like `358153851`.

The values are saved in MS SQL Server database. I would like to convert it to datetime format.

The issue here is that I'm not familiar with the Perl language, and I don't know how to integrated the Perl conversion script with SSIS / Tsql.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: It's almost surely a timestamp in unix epoch format, which your server surely has functions capable of manipulating it.

Answer (score 4):

Like @mceda said, if this is an epoch time, you could also get a MS SQL timestamp via Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime::Format::Epoch;
use DateTime::Format::MSSQL;

my $formatter = DateTime::Format::Epoch->new(
        epoch          => $dt,
        unit           => 'seconds',
        type           => 'int',
        skip_leap_secondss => 1,
        start_at       => 0,
        local_epoch    => undef,
    );
my $dt = $formatter->parse_datetime(358153851);
print DateTime::Format::MSSQL->format_datetime($dt);
```

This will create a [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) object from the epoch time, and convert it to a MS SQL formatted date time string.

Answer (score 1):

If your time is indeed UNIX time, it is simply represents a number of seconds from 1970-01-01.

```
DECLARE @UNIX_TIME INT = 358153851;
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME;

SELECT  @DATE=DATEADD(SECOND, @UNIX_TIME, '19700101');
```

For the number in the question, converted time is `1981-05-08 07:10:51.000`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $t = time();

print (sec_to_sql_str($t));

sub sec_to_sql_str
{
    my $in = shift;

    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,undef,undef,undef) = localtime($in);
    return sprintf ("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", 1900 + $year, 1 + $mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about conversion in Perl :) Let's see which direction he was interested in.